# How to ignore objects that don't satisfy the "class" conditions?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract some data from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Belarusian_citizens) page and I want to extract only
non-empty links. Empty links have class named "new" and I want to filter result by this condition. For this I'm using the following code:

```
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Belarusian_citizens"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

visa_req_table = soup.findAll("table", "nowraplinks hlist collapsible autocollapse navbox-inner")[1]
tables_regions = visa_req_table.findAll("table", "nowraplinks navbox-subgroup")
for single_table in tables_regions:
    for a in single_table.findAll('a', href=True):
        if a.find(attrs={'class': 'new'}):
            a.extract()
        print a.text, a['href']
```

But I can't remove empty links from the final result, using the code above. Can you tell me please, what am I doing wrong?

**UPD:**
After I corrected my code to the following form:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Belarusian_citizens"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
visa_req_table = soup.findAll("table", "nowraplinks hlist collapsible autocollapse navbox-inner")[1]
tables_regions = visa_req_table.findAll("table", "nowraplinks navbox-subgroup")
for single_table in tables_regions:
    non_new_links = lambda tag: (getattr(tag, 'name') == 'a' and
                                 'href' in a.attrs and
                                 'new' not in a.attrs.get('class', []))
    for a in single_table.find_all(non_new_links):
        print a.text, a['href']
```

I saw the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../2.py", line 16, in <module>
    for a in single_table.find_all(non_new_links):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1180, in find_all
    return self._find_all(name, attrs, text, limit, generator, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 505, in _find_all
    found = strainer.search(i)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1540, in search
    found = self.search_tag(markup)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1496, in search_tag
    or (markup and self._matches(markup, self.name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 1578, in _matches
    return match_against(markup)
  File ".../2.py", line 14, in <lambda>
    'href' in a.attrs and
NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

What should I correct in my code to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the passage of time, BeautifulSoup has now gained a *much* better CSS selector engine. As of version 4.7, the [SoupSieve project](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/) has become part of the standard BeautifulSoup toolset.

You can ask for elements that have an attribute that is **not** equal to something with the [`[attr!="value"]` attribute selector](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/#attribute-selectors). Provided the `new` class is the *only* class on those links, you can use this to filter out such links here:

```
visa_req_table = soup.select_one("table.wikitable")  # first table is the visa table
active_links = visa_req_table.select('td a[class!="new"]')
```

Below is my original answer.

---

The only way to ask BeautifulSoup to ask for elements that do **not** match a criteria is to give it a function to test elements against:

```
non_new_links = lambda tag: (getattr(tag, 'name') == 'a' and
                             'href' in tag.attrs and 
                             'new' not in tag.attrs.get('class', [])
for a in single_table.find_all(non_new_links):
```

The `non_new_links` function only matches tags that fit all 3 of your criteria.

I'd simplify your table search to:

```
for cell in soup.find_all('td', class_='nav-inner'):
```